# Filter Ansible output from lineinfile

Tags: ansible

I'm attempting to audit my systems via files copied to a single host. The default output is very verbose. I would like to see just the pertinent fields of Ansible log output; that way, over 1000 hosts, I can zero into my problems more quickly. . When my play is successful, I'd like to just see:

```
ok: u'/mnt/inventory/hostname999'
```

I have a playbook that looks like this:

```
- hosts: 'localhost'
  name: Playbook for the Audit for our infrastructure.
  gather_facts: False
  become: no
  connection: local
  roles:
    - { role: network, tags: network }
```

My network role main.xml file looks like this:

```
---
- name: find matching pattern files
  find:
    paths: "/mnt/inventory"
    patterns: "hostname*"
    file_type: directory
  register: subdirs

- name: check files for net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
  no_log: False
  lineinfile:
    name: "{{ item.path }}/sysctl.conf"
    line: "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0"
    state: present
  with_items: "{{ subdirs.files }}"
  register: conf
  check_mode: yes
  failed_when: (conf is changed) or (conf is failed)
- debug:
    msg: "CONF OUTPUT: {{ conf }}"
```

But I get log output like this:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'uid': 0, u'woth': False, u'mtime': 1546922126.0,
u'inode': 773404, u'isgid': False, u'size': 4096, u'roth': True, u'isuid': 
False, u'isreg': False, u'pw_name': u'root', u'gid': 0, u'ischr': False, 
u'wusr': False, u'xoth': True, u'rusr': True, u'nlink': 12, u'issock': 
False, u'rgrp': True, u'gr_name': u'root', u'path': 
u'/mnt/inventory/hostname999', u'xusr': True, u'atime': 1546930801.0, 
u'isdir': True, u'ctime': 1546922126.0, u'wgrp': False, u'xgrp': True, 
u'dev': 51, u'isblk': False, u'isfifo': False, u'mode': u'0555', u'islnk': 
False})
```

Furthermore, my debug message of CONF OUTPUT never shows and I have no idea why not.

I have reviewed https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5564 and other articles but they just seem to refer to items like shell commands that send stuff to stdout, which lineinfile does not.

Answer (score 0):

> But I get log output like this:

Then you likely want to use [`loop_control:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#loop-control) with a `label: "{{ item.path }}"` child:

```
- lineinfile:
    # as before
  with_items: "{{ subdirs.files }}"
  loop_control:
     label: "{{ item.path }}"
```

which will get you closer to what you want:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=/mnt/inventory/hostname999)
```

---

> Furthermore, my debug message of CONF OUTPUT never shows and I have no idea why not.

The best guess I have for that one is that maybe the verbosity needs to be adjusted:

```
- debug:
    msg: "CONF OUTPUT: {{ conf }}"
    verbosity: 0
```

but it works for me, so maybe there is something else special about your ansible setup. I guess try the `verbosity:` and see if it helps. Given what you are actually doing with that `msg:`, you may be much happier with just passing `conf` directly to `debug`:

```
- debug:
    var: conf
```

since it will render *much* nicer because ansible knows it is a `dict`, rather that just effectively calling `str(conf)` which (as you saw above) does not format very nicely.